# Extract text from pdf file using pdfplumber

Tags: python, pdf, pdfplumber

I want to extract text from a pdf file, tried:

```
directory = r'C:\Users\foo\folder'

for x in os.listdir(directory):
    print(x)
    x = x.replace('.pdf','')
    filename = os.fsdecode(x)
    print(x)

    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        with pdfplumber.open(x) as pdf1:
            page1 = pdf1.pages[0]
            text1 = page1.extract_text()
            print(text1)
```

and it printed:

```
20170213091544343.pdf
20170213091544343
```

Seeing the file has a name of `20170213091544343`, I added:

```
    else:
        with pdfplumber.open(x) as pdf1:
                page1 = pdf1.pages[0]
                text1 = page1.extract_text()
                print(text1)
```

to read the file in case the file name doesn't have `.pdf` and it caught error:

```
20170213091544343.pdf
20170213091544343
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-e370b214f9ba> in <module>
     16 
     17     else:
---> 18         with pdfplumber.open(x) as pdf1:
     19                 page1 = pdf1.pages[0]
     20                 text1 = page1.extract_text()

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pdfplumber\pdf.py in open(cls, path_or_fp, **kwargs)
     56     def open(cls, path_or_fp, **kwargs):
     57         if isinstance(path_or_fp, (str, pathlib.Path)):
---> 58             fp = open(path_or_fp, "rb")
     59             inst = cls(fp, **kwargs)
     60             inst.close = fp.close

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20170213091544343'
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns just the filename.  You need the directory too.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon, could you please elaborate?

Comment: you have to use full path `os.path.join(directory, x)` and you have to keep extension `.pdf` - to open `C:\Users\foo\folder\20170213091544343.pdf` instead of `20170213091544343`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir()` gives only `filename` and you have to join it with `directory`

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):

    fullpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)

    #print(fullpath)
```

And you have to keep exension `.pdf`

```
import os
import pdfplumber

directory = r'C:\Users\foo\folder'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):

        fullpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        #print(fullpath)

        #all_text = ""

        with pdfplumber.open(fullpath) as pdf:
            for page in pdf.pages:
                text = page.extract_text()
                print(text)
                #all_text += text

        #print(all_text)
```

or with page number

```
        with pdfplumber.open(fullpath) as pdf:
            for number, page in enumerate(pdf.pages, 1):
                print('--- page', number, '---')
                text = page.extract_text()
                print(text)
```

Comment: Hi furas, thanks for your answer. But it returned `None` when there is clearly content in the page?

Comment: it can means there is no text on page. It may have all as images.

Comment: I see, is it possible to extract text from image?

Comment: it would need some `OCR` program - like `tesseract` (created by Google) and module `pytesseract` - to convert image to text.

Comment: I see, I tested this solution on another pdf file, however, it seems to produce text from another file, any thought as to what might go wrong?

Comment: BTW: you check only first page - if text is on next pages then you should use `for`-loop

Comment: check `print(fullpath)` and use this path in any PDF viewer to check if you really open correct file. Maybe it gives different text then you expect because you open different file.

Comment: I added `for`-loop in answer

Comment: Indeed, it printed a different fullpath, although I've specified the file name I want. It's weird that it seems like the first file in the list of `os.listdir(directory)`, which in my case is `Downloads` and has a myriad of files. So I changed `if filename.endswith('.pdf'):` into `if filename.endswith('the_complete_name_of_the_file_i_want.pdf'):` and it seems to work

Comment: if you want to use `'the_complete_name_of_the_file_i_want.pdf` then you don't need to check `endswith()` and you don't need `os.listdir()` but use directly `open('directory/the_complete_name_of_the_file_i_want.pdf')`

Comment: Thanks furas, I searched for some `pytesseract` examples as you suggested such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292713/11901732) but could never get `ImageMagick ` installed, is it necessary for me to use `ImageMagick ` if I want to extract text from image in pdf?

Comment: I don't remeber if this need `ImageMagick` - first install `tessract` from Google and test it without Python - directly in console `tesseract.exe file.pdf`

Comment: it may needs `ImageMagick` to convert every page in `pdf` into image -  because `tesseract` may need images. On ImageMagick's page you can see many [installers for Windows](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll have a look.